# The proper way to setup foreign key association when using inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

There are two tables in my database: `Masters` and `Details`.
These tables are related one-to-many with a foreign key constraint, where's `Masters` is a primary key table, and `Details` is a foreign key table.

I want to use inheritance in my model both for entities from `Masters` table:

```
abstract class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Master_1 : Master
{
    // other properties
}

class Master_2: Master
{
    // other properties
}
```

and for entities from `Details` table:

```
abstract class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Detail_1 : Detail
{
    // other properties
}

class Detail_2: Detail
{
    // other properties
}

class Detail_3: Detail
{
    // other properties
}
```

But what about foreign key?
Conceptually, `Master_1` should contains only `Detail_1` details, and `Master_2` should contains `Detail_2` or `Detail_3` details.

If I would abstract from Entity Framework, I'd add intermediate base class for `Detail_2` and `Detail_3`:

```
   abstract class Detail_2_Or_3 : Detail {}
   class Detail_2 : Detail_2_Or_3 {}
   class Detail_3 : Detail_2_Or_3 {}
```

and make my `Master` generic:

```
abstract class Master<TDetail>
    where TDetail : Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Collection<TDetail> Details { get; private set; }
}

class Master_1 : Master<Detail_1> {}
class Master_2 : Master<Detail_2_Or_3> {}
```

But how this can be achieved using Entity Framework? I don't like the solution, when `Master` has a collection of `Details`, because this can't provide the compile-time guarantee.

I'm looking for the way without additional layer over `Master` and `Detail` hierarchy.
Any ideas?

Comment: This is an interesting read and will hopefully provide you with food for thought... http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx

Comment: @PaulZahra: I don't think, that the description of TPC inheritance could help. May be I'm missing something?

Comment: Did you look at TPT and TPH?

Comment: The question isn't about a choosing of inheritance model (which will be TPT in this particular case). The question is about how to configure the relationship, thus it will provide compile-time safety.

Comment: With an abstract class, the association must refer to an instance of one of its subclasses only.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, and I haven't tried it out fully with EF, but...

Why not set things up just as you say, and provide the compile time safety with a restrictive set of public methods on you domain objects?

That is, Master is set up in EF with a collection of Details, but you can only add an instance of Detail_1 to a instance of Master_1 etc. Then you could have a method that returns a strongly typed collection appropriate to the base type as well.

Here is the code:

```
public abstract class Master<TDetail> where TDetail : Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; private set; }

    public abstract void AddDetail(TDetail detail);
    public abstract List<TDetail> GetDetails();
}

public class Master_1 : Master<Detail_1> 
{
    public override void AddDetail(Detail_1 detail) 
    {
        Details.Add(detail);
    }

    public override List<Detail_1> GetDetails()
    {
        return Details.Select(d => (Detail_1)d).ToList();
    }
}

public class Master_2 : Master<Detail_2_Or_3> 
{
    public override void AddDetail(Detail_2_Or_3 detail)
    {
        Details.Add(detail);
    }

    public override List<Detail_2_Or_3> GetDetails()
    {
        return Details.Select(d => (Detail_2_Or_3)d).ToList();
    }
}

public abstract class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foriegn Key
    public int MasterId { get; private set;}
}

public class Detail_1 : Detail { }

public abstract class Detail_2_Or_3 : Detail { }
public class Detail_2 : Detail_2_Or_3 { }
public class Detail_3 : Detail_2_Or_3 { }
```